# Conductive Emission Help needed

Tags: dc-dc-converter, noise, emi-filtering

Conductive Emission Help needed :
Have a DC to DC converter 28 VDC to 12 V DC  2A , that is loaded by a PWM load , the supply wires contain unwanted  Differential and common mode  conductive Emission signals , any suggestion how to reduce the outages ? especially at the low frequency about 1KHz , any feedback welcome .

Comment: A schematic would help.

Comment: Twist wires. They should be close as possible. Also wires thicker.

Comment: Pi filter with a CM choke and caps may be enough, otherwise adding RF caps to gnd for better CM rejection,  Pi with CLLC filter

Comment: Higher order filters can also be used on ungrounded inputs. http://tonnesoftware.com/elsie.html